# Saving a text file

Tags: matlab, file, save

I want to save a matrix as .text with a variable filename. Currently I'm saving my file using the function dlmwrite(name,matrix); This is only working with a pre-set filename. Is there a way to make the name of the file variable?

A window that pops up that ask for a filename to write to just as 'Uigetfile' does with opening a file would be ideal. Does anyone know if Matlab got a function just like that for writing text files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`uiputfile`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/uiputfile.html) to graphically get the file name. For example:

```
[filename, pathname, filterindex] = uiputfile('', 'Select file');
```

Then use `dlmwrite` to save a variable, say `data`, to that file:

```
dlmwrite(fullfile(pathname, filename), data)
```